# Restore purchase not working in Flutter/Google Play

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, flutter-in-app-purchase

I have implemented in app purchases (IAP) as per `in_app_purchase` package [example](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/example)

I am able to buy a product from the store (I only have one set up). But when it comes to testing "user has a new phone" scenario, the restore purchases does not seem to work. No error either.

I've implemented this in a provider pattern. Store connection is initialized like this:

```
_isStoreAvailable = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
```

Purchasing is implemented this way:

```
 Future<void> initializePurchase() async {
      ProductDetailsResponse response =
          await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_productIds);
      if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
        // Handle the error.
        print("not found product in store!)");
      } else {
        PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(
          productDetails: response.productDetails.first,
        );
        _inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
      }
  }
```

I listen for changes using this code:

```
  final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
        _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    _subscription =
        purchaseUpdated.listen((List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      print("listen error: $error");
    });
```

...and this

```
  Future<void> _listenToPurchaseUpdated(
      List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    for (final PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (purchaseDetails.status != PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          //handle error
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
            purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {

          setLicense(StoreLicenseStatus.paid);
          notifyListeners();

          if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
            await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

User can request purchases to be restored using this code:

```
 Future<void> restorePurchases() async {
    await _inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
  }
```

Everything except restore works. I can buy a product, clear data, and when I start the app again, if I try to buy, I get a message from the store "you already own this item". So the store recognizes that the product was already purchased, great! But when I click "restore" nothing happens.

Am I missing something here?

This is on an emulator (Pixel 4 API 32), also on a real device.

Comment: Have the same issue. This definitely used to work, so I suspect something is broken on Google's side again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in [in_app_purchase_android](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase_android) package.

> The new billing api uses an asynchronous listener in
> queryPurchasesAsync. There was a change that has the listener be
> invoked on the background thread instead of the main UI thread, which
> is causing the querypurchases to never complete.

In the meantime add this to your `pubspec.yaml` as a workaround:

```
dependency_overrides:
in_app_purchase_android: 0.2.2+8
```

For more details see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107454)

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same situation for me. Restore purchase doesn’t restore anything though I definitely have a purchase.

Additionally I have to mention that it works perfectly when I build the app locally (both debug and release modes), but the issue appears when I build it with CICD and put on Firebase App Distribution or Play Console Internal testing.

GitHub [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107454).